# Asp.Net MVC Action link for paragraph or icons

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I have to give action link to both icon and text. How can I do this with @html.Actionlink. I tried to add icon html code inside actionlink as text but it didnt work. How can we handle these cases with out using normal anchor tag?

```
    <div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Request", "Request", "MyRequest")
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot with `ActionLink()`, but you can use `<a href="Url.Action(...)" ...>......</a>` and add the icon and text between the tags

Answer (score 1):

As @Stephen in the comments mentioned, you can't use `ActionLink()` and include an icon. You're going to have to use an anchor. Your code in this format would look as follows:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Request", "MyRequest")">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"></span>
    <span>Request</span>            
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript code, like :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Request", "Request", "MyRequest", new { @class = "btn-primary", id = "btn-actionlink-export" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn-actionlink-export').append('<span class="icon-file-excel position-right"></span>');
    });
</script>
```